# Images generated by Base64 from Ruby on Rails are broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, base64

I'm creating a form that has a multi upload handled with React, so I have base64 strings that I want to "convert back" to images. 
For having testing it both before and after form submission, I can assure the base64 is not corrupted.

I found several questions related on SO about how to recreate images from base64 with Rails, but I had to tweak it a bit, and now my generated images are broken.

Here is how I handled it:

```
def portfolio_params
    params.require(:portfolio).permit(:title, :creation_time,
                                      :public, :content, { illustrations: [] },
                                      :slug, :thumbnail, :website, :tags)
    port_params[:illustrations] = parse_image_data(port_params[:illustrations]) if port_params[:illustrations]
    port_params
  end

def parse_image_data(base64)
    require 'fileutils'
    filename = 'portfolio-file-'
    path = 'public/uploads/portfolio/' + Time.now.strftime('%d%m%Y%H%i%s')

    # Check if directory exists, creates it if not
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(path) unless File.directory?(path)

    # creation of the response variable
    response = []

    # Since I'm getting an array (multiupload), I have to loop through it
    base64.each_with_index do |b, i|

      # Extracts the file format (png, jpg, jpeg..)
      _in_content_type, format, _encoding, _string = b.split(/[:\/;,]/)[1..4]

      # Creates the file with the index so the file doesn't get rewritten
      File.open(path + '/' + filename + i.to_s + '.' + format, 'wb') do |f|

        # Fills it with the decoded base64 string
        f.write(Base64.decode64(b))
      end

      # Response made to the params so that the image path gets saved instead of the base64
      response.push(path + '/' + filename + i.to_s + '.' + format)
    end

  response
end
```

Theorically everything works: my databases saves the path, the file gets created, but... not correctly.

I'm not exactly sure of what am I doing, where did I do wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might (highly not likely) be in the same trouble, the problem is that the "base64" prefix, that looks like the following:

```
data:image/gif;base64,
```

is not recognized by the method `Base64.decode64`, only, what's **after**.

So I changed my code for the following:

```
base64.each_with_index do |b, i|
  _in_content_type, format, _encoding, _string = b.split(/[:\/;,]/)[1..4]

  File.open(path + '/' + filename + i.to_s + '.' + format, 'wb') do |f|
    f.write(Base64.decode64(b.partition('base64,').last))
  end

  response.push(path + '/' + filename + i.to_s + '.' + format)
end
```

The code `b.partition('base64,')` creates an array with everything before AND after what I pu in the partition's argument.